# Form validation problem, code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I really don't know why this validation doesn't work.

this is my html:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type='text/javascript' src="scripts.js"></script>
<title>Test Page!</title>
</head>

<body>
<form onsubmit ="return validateFormOnSubmit(this)" name="myForm" action = "testForm.html">
<input name="textField" type="text" value="" size="50" id= "textfield"  /> <br />
<input name="button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my javascript file:

```
function isURL(fld){
    var error = "";
    var regex = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
    if(regex.test(fld.value)){
        error = "No URL's Allowed!";
    }
    else{
        error = "";
    }
    return error;
}

function validateFormOnSubmit(myForm) {
var reason = "";

  reason += isURL(myForm.textField);


  if (reason != "") {
    alert("there's something wrong: \n" + reason);
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

**update:** is the action really required? testpage.html is just an empty html file here!

**update 2:** The problem is I don't see any message or alert.

Comment: What exactly is wrong?  What does or does not happen?

Comment: I don't see any message or alert..

Answer (score 1):

It works fine, your scripts.js file isn't loaded properly or an old version is cached in your browser

Comment: Why is scripts.js not loaded properly? I just emptied the cache, that wasn't the problem.

Comment: Add it inline in your code and you'll see it works, I've tried it. Must be the file doesn't exist or it's in another directory

Comment: I put the code in the .html file and it still doesn't work! I am using wamp server, I tried to put offline and online again and that doesn't help either.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you, I've copied your code into a blank .html document on my desktop, moved the script inline and it works. IE and Chrome.

Comment: I am testing on localhost, like this: localhost/myFolder/index.html. This is really weird, I don't understand.

Comment: No I mean what text are you testing as an input?

Comment: I tested both urls and normal strings. None of them shows an alert!

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you're passing in the form, rather than the field that you're trying to validate.

Comment: They're passing in the form which they want to validate, that's perfectly valid

Comment: In validateFormOnSubmit I pass in the form, but then I have this line in it: isURL(myForm.textField), so it's now the textField..